# Node.js: how does this require work?

Tags: node.js, require

I was trying out Joose with node.js and managed to produce code like this:

```
require('joose'); // WHAT?

Class("Dog", {
    methods: {
        bark: function() { console.log('woof'); }
    }
});

var dog = new Dog();
dog.bark();
```

I have thought that every `require` in node.js must be assigned to a variable, contrary to PHP in which you just require the file and it works as if you'd copy its contents to that place.

In this situation `Class` seems to infiltrate the main scope by itself since if I remove the `require` statement I get a `ReferenceError: Class is not defined`.

How does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joose injects the global variable `Class` (global.Class = ...), that's why it's visible without assigning it into your code specifically.